# opencv identifier "Mat" is undefined when used in a header file

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm using visual studio professional 2013. There I used opencv. And I have linked all opencv libraries correctly.

1. The programs work in main.cpp ( i have tested lot of opencv programs)
2. The same program that used in a class, giving undefined error (even a simple mat object cannot create inside the class that gives undefined errors.)

How do i resolve this problem ?

Please find below i used code ( This undefined Mat problem couldn't occur in  main.cpp)

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> // import no include errors
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> // import no include errors 
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>       // import no include errors
class DepthImage
{

public:
    DepthImage();
    ~DepthImage();
private:
    Mat image; //identifier "Mat" is undefined  
};
```

Comment: Don't include `stdafx.h` in a header. `stdafx.h` should be the first include in every cpp file but never include in a header.

Comment: @drescherjm i tried but I'm getting same issue. please find below
https://s23.postimg.org/ne23bgcaj/Capture.png

Comment: try cv::Mat data;

Comment: Agreed, you are forgetting the cv namespace.

Comment: @Angelica thank you i forget the name space. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#pragma once
//#include "stdafx.h" never in header file
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> // import no include errors
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> // import no include errors 
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>       // import no include errors
class DepthImage
{

public:
    DepthImage();
    ~DepthImage();
private:
    cv::Mat image; //no more identifier "Mat" is undefined  
};
```

hope that helps you